# NoHttpResponseException : server failed to respond - with Zuul Proxy and AuthServer

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a hard scenario here that I will try to explain and get some clue about how to solve it:

I'm using **Netflix Zuul** as gateway to my RESTful services. This proxy invokes upon an **Authorization Server** (a third part one, deployed on my local machine - docker image, for example) and the major part of the times, it works well. - it follows some configuration from my proxy just to clarify (propositally ommited some parts because they are not required to understand the whole picture):

```
...
authserver:
    hostname: myAccessManagement.example.com # which I have also defined in my hosts
    port: 8080
    contextPath: myContextX

zuul:
    debug:
        request: true
    routes:
        user: 
           path: /userinfo/**
           stripPrefix: false
           url: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/oauth2
...
```

The issue is: Sometimes it seems that Zuul invokes my AuthServer and it works fine, but in another ones, zuul tries to call and this stack arises:

**Error during filtering**

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: myAccessManagement.example.com:8080 failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:310) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M4.jar:1.1.0.M4]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:273) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M4.jar:1.1.0.M4]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:168) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M4.jar:1.1.0.M4]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M4.jar:1.1.0.M4]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.doFilter(RequestDumperFilter.java:203) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
```

The rest follows here: https://gist.github.com/fernandoabcampos/a410f5e5dee730eeb542#file-error-during-proxy-authserver-invoke

I searched a lot about the issue, but I couldn't find anything conclusive.
One good option that another team was facing is that they have to set a **keepalive_timeout** for their proxy - but it was a different scenario and the tools they are using were not the same stack.

**Edited here:**

---

Essentially, there is no much code involved(from my part):

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableRetry
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    public static class OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        }

    }
}
```

---

All the magic is done on backstage by Spring stuff - I mean I am not invoking directly through an HttpClient / RestTemplate, etc.

[An image to demonstrate the full 'system'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eagha.png)

Anyone have an opinion to share? It'll be pretty useful...
And I apologize if it's anyway vague, if you need another configuration or more description, just let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to actually invoke the call to your auth server? Also, what version of apache HttpClient is being used?

Comment: @NickDeFazio, I just edited my question to include some informations, but in fact, I'm not invoking directly my AuthServer, for instance - in a HttpClient, it is done by Spring.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Hard to say whats going on, but first I would go to eureka admin site + logs of "myAccessManagement.example.com" and try to figure out if there is something strange with register / deregister app from eureka. Maybe app is down but instance is still registered? ( which is default behaviour, more details https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication )

Comment: The worst part is that it is totally intermittent.
Now I guess (it needs more investigation from my part to be concise) that one option could fit - or at least explain this behaviour:

In summary, the client (zuul in this case) seems think that the connection from the pool with AuthServer is still open, but AuthServer has closed it already as it has expired.

Comment: Then Zuul tries to connect to AuthServer and gets the exception. 
Next time Zuul retries and might get a brand new connection and then is working.
That's why I believe that I got this (intermittent behaviour) if I try to log in and out several times in a row without a break, everything seems to work fine. However at the moment I take a break after a login, let's say 30 sec - 1 min then it's very likely you get the error.
I've found a similar situation here: [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: myAccessManagement.example.com:8080 failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) ~[httpclient-4.4.jar:4.4]
at
```

This might be a longshot, but there is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1610) in HttpClient 4.4 that looks like it might be the [source of your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104643/httpclienterror-the-target-server-failed-to-respond). Try upgrading to 4.4.1.

Comment: you are completely right.
It works!!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @FernandoBarbeiroCampos did you just add the dependency to the http client to your gradle file, or how did you solve this issue? I'm having the exact same behaviour for a while now

Comment: How did you solve your issue. How did you exactly update the http client version?