# Zuul Forwarding Exception caused by org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, thymeleaf, netflix-zuul

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

Been a while since I've asked a question so if I forget some information, just let me know and I will gladly add.

We have recently uncovered some issues occurring in our client-server.  We are running a Spring server that handles client requests and renders HTML via Thymeleaf.  We are using Zuul as a way to redirect our many client routes to a single Spring endpoint that serves up a single bundle so that no matter where a user refreshes, they will receive the bundle we want them to get.  This seems to work most of the time but once every minute or so (out of thousands a minute) we get a zuul forwarding exception like so:

```
[2m2020-11-30 02:26:51.023[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m50[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [33m[trace=,span=][0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter  [0;39m 
[2m:[0;39m Error during filteringcom.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error     at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.handleException(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:261) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:241) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at 
com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]     at 
com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]   
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]   at 
com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]   at 
com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]  at 
com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]  at 
com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]     at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]  at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]  at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]  at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapper.doFilter(ClientCertificateMapper.java:79) [client_certificate_mapper-1.11.0_RELEASE.jar:na]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]  at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]

 Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond    at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]   at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]    at 
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]   at 
org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]    at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]     at 
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]  at 
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]    at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]  at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]  at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]  at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]   at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]   at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:422) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]  at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:341) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:236) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]     ... 61 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, we are using HttpClient 4.5.12. I saw similar issues occurring in 4.4 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104643/httpclienterror-the-target-server-failed-to-respond) but we upgraded and the issue persisted.  In the same post @daimarom commented that perhaps the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` could be causing an issue.  This is how we configured our pool manager:

```
 @Bean
 public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager() {
        
     PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
     connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(5000);
     connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(40);
     connectionManager.setMaxTotal(15);
     return connectionManager;
 }

 @Bean
 public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
     return HttpClients.custom()
         .disableAutomaticRetries()
         .setSSLContext(sslContext())
         .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory())
         .setConnectionManager(connectionManager())
         .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
         .build();
 }
```

Playing aroung with the connection manager parameters did not help.

We had a Zuul filter but made our routing completely configuration based to rule out any logical errors.  Currently our Zuul configuration looks like such:

```
zuul:
  sensitive-headers: 
  host.socket-timeout-millis: 60000
  routes:
    api:
      strip-prefix: false
      path: /api/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piserver}"
    extract:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/extract/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    legal:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/legal/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-vin:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/vin/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-vin:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/vin/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-odometer:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/odometer/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-odometer:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/odometer/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-rear:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/rear/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-rear:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/rear/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-rear-passenger:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/rear-passenger/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-rear-passenger:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/rear-passenger/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-front-passenger:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/front-passenger/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-front-passenger:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/front-passenger/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-front-driver:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/front-driver/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-front-driver:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/front-driver/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-rear-driver:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/rear-driver/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-rear-driver:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/rear-driver/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-damage-left:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/damage-left/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-damage-left:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/damage-left/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-damage-center:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/damage-capture-instructions/damage-center/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-damage-center:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/damage-recapture-instructions/damage-center/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-damage-right:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/damage-capture-instructions/damage-right/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-damage-right:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/damage-recapture-instructions/damage-right/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    capture-damages:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/capture-instructions/damages/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    recapture-damages:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/recapture-instructions/damages/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    uploading:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /web2/uploading/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    submit:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /submit/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    intake-processing:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /intake-processing/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    already-submitted:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /already-submitted/**
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    submit-v1:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /submit
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    intake-processing-v1:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /intake-processing
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
    already-submitted-v1:
      strip-prefix: true
      path: /already-submitted
      url: "${validation.urls.piclient}/validate"
```

This used to be much more succinct in the routing filter when we simply reset the request URI in the current context but as I mentioned before, now this is all configuration based.

All of our dependencies are defined here:

```
dependencies {

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:10.7.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul'

    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.37'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.37'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.37'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

I feel like I am missing something completely obvious here but our manager who was very experienced with Zuul recently left.  Please let me know if there is any additional information I can add here.  Thank you in advance for any help.

[UPDATE]
I have recently attempted taking the entire pool manager out of the configuration.  The problem has persisted.  Now the configuration for the HttpClient looks like the following:

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
    return HttpClients.custom()
        .disableAutomaticRetries()
        .setSSLContext(sslContext())
        .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory())
        // .setConnectionManager(connectionManager())
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
}
```

Also, we tried with and without a spring security configuration chain explicitly defined.  Nothing helped.

Comment: We had a similar issue, have you tried  connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Hi brijesh. No, I have not tried this.  I will attempt it with an idle timeout of 1 second as you suggested.  Should this line be called in the configuration file or before each request made?

Comment: I've seen that maybe it gets called on a separate thread entirely?

Comment: That should be configured with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager bean, you have that code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so @brijesh mentioned a potential solution in the comments that I have yet to try but I did end up deploying another "fixing" change.  It's more of a recovery from the issue which is mostly likely still occurring.  I simply enabled automatic retrying by commenting out the following line:

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
    return HttpClients.custom()
        // .disableAutomaticRetries()
        .setSSLContext(sslContext())
        .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory())
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager())
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
}
```

For anyone who does not explicitly configure their HttpClient settings, this shouldn't be an issue since the default is to retry 3 times.

For people who do configure these settings and are having issues with the connection manager, I will soon attempt @brijesh's approach (with automatic retrying disabled) to see if the solution resolves the root cause.  I will update the answer here once I've completed this.